# Is it possible to adjust number of sub-jobs for GNU parallel after invocation?

Tags: process-management, gnu-parallel

If I have already started a job with GNU parallel in a similar fashion to:

```
$ cat jobs | parallel -j 70 "program {};"
```

is it possible, by e.g. some signal, to adjust the number of jobs of this parallel job? So that I could indicate to `parallel` that there should now be run at most `75` sub-jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Number-of-simultaneous-jobs

> ## Number of simultaneous jobs
>
> :
>
> --jobs can read from a file which is re-read when a job finishes:
>
> ```
> echo 50% > my_jobs
> /usr/bin/time parallel -N0 --jobs my_jobs sleep 1 :::: num128 &
> sleep 1
> echo 0 > my_jobs
> wait
> ```
>
> The first second
> only 50% of the CPU cores will run a job. Then 0 is put into my_jobs
> and then the rest of the jobs will be started in parallel.

I highly recommend spending an hour walking through the tutorial. Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Thanks! Needs a bit of forethought, but I can do that.